# Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString() - on calling json post method

Tags: android, json, jsonresponse

Code to call the api is as mentioned and the json response post method. error while calling json object at the line"JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject(response);". Response available but error occurs as"Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()"

```
String PROJECT_URL = url+ r.getString(R.string.api_Get_two);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, PROJECT_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        pendingDataList.clear();
                        Log.d("JSON", response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject(response);  (Error here)
                            JSONArray pendingChallans = (mJsonObj).getJSONArray("Day");
                            if(pendingChallans.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i <pendingChallans.length() ; i++) {
                                PendingData pending = new PendingData();
                                 JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) pendingChallans.get(i);
                                  pending.setRowType(obj.getString("RowType"));
                                  pendingDataList.add(pending);
                                }
                            }else {
                                new Dialogs(mContext, "No Data Found .").createDialogWithMsg();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally {
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            pcdRecyclerview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
```

````
JSON:

{
    "Day": [{
            "RowType": 1,
            "Sl": {
                "Value": "",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Particulars": {
                "Value": "PEN ",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value1": {
                "Value": "",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value2": {
                "Value": "",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value3": {
                "Value": "",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "NextLevelZoomData": "",
            "NextLevelZoomType": 0
        },
        {
            "RowType": 2,
            "Sl": {
                "Value": "SL.",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Particulars": {
                "Value": "CUS",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value1": {
                "Value": "BQty",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value2": {
                "Value": "Amount",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value3": {
                "Value": "Ood",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "NextLevelZoomData": "",
            "NextLevelZoomType": 0
        },
        {
            "RowType": 3,
            "Sl": {
                "Value": "1. ",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Particulars": {
                "Value": "ETH",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value1": {
                "Value": "2",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value2": {
                "Value": "7",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value3": {
                "Value": "165 / 165",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "NextLevelZoomData": "[{\"UnitFields\":[{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Challan No.\",\"DisplayOrder\":1,\"Value\":\"2 / 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"No. of Days\",\"DisplayOrder\":2,\"Value\":\"153\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Bal. Qty\",\"DisplayOrder\":3,\"Value\":\"1.00 PCS\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":0},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Item\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"Value\":\"WAVE\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Rate\",\"DisplayOrder\":5,\"Value\":\"398.00\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Sale\",\"DisplayOrder\":6,\"Value\":\"L A\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Location\",\"DisplayOrder\":7,\"Value\":\" FLOOR\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Comment\",\"DisplayOrder\":8,\"Value\":\"SELECTION~\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Supplier\",\"DisplayOrder\":9,\"Value\":\"gtt\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1}],\"Unit\":\"09\"},{\"UnitcodeFields\":[{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Challan No.\",\"DisplayOrder\":1,\"Value\":\"1/ 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"No. of Days\",\"DisplayOrder\":2,\"Value\":\"139\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Bal. Qty\",\"DisplayOrder\":3,\"Value\":\"1.00 PCS\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":0},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Item\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"Value\":\"EMjB\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Rate\",\"DisplayOrder\":5,\"Value\":\"37,590.00\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Sale\",\"DisplayOrder\":6,\"Value\":\"L A\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Location\",\"DisplayOrder\":7,\"Value\":\"MM 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Comment\",\"DisplayOrder\":8,\"Value\":\"PERSONAL\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Supplier\",\"DisplayOrder\":9,\"Value\":\"GOUR\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1}],\"Unit\":\"08\"}]",
            "NextLevelZoomType": 2
        },
        {
            "RowType": 3,
            "Sl": {
                "Value": "2. ",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Particulars": {
                "Value": "SAE",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value1": {
                "Value": "1",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value2": {
                "Value": "30",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value3": {
                "Value": "1",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "NextLevelZoomData": "[{\"UnitFields\":[{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Challan No.\",\"DisplayOrder\":1,\"Value\":\"2 / 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"No. of Days\",\"DisplayOrder\":2,\"Value\":\"153\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Bal. Qty\",\"DisplayOrder\":3,\"Value\":\"1.00 PCS\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":0},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Item\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"Value\":\"WAVE\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Rate\",\"DisplayOrder\":5,\"Value\":\"398.00\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Sale\",\"DisplayOrder\":6,\"Value\":\"L A\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Location\",\"DisplayOrder\":7,\"Value\":\" FLOOR\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Comment\",\"DisplayOrder\":8,\"Value\":\"SELECTION~\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Supplier\",\"DisplayOrder\":9,\"Value\":\"gtt\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1}],\"Unit\":\"09\"},{\"UnitcodeFields\":[{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Challan No.\",\"DisplayOrder\":1,\"Value\":\"1/ 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"No. of Days\",\"DisplayOrder\":2,\"Value\":\"139\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Bal. Qty\",\"DisplayOrder\":3,\"Value\":\"1.00 PCS\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":0},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Item\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"Value\":\"EMjB\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Rate\",\"DisplayOrder\":5,\"Value\":\"37,590.00\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Sale\",\"DisplayOrder\":6,\"Value\":\"L A\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Location\",\"DisplayOrder\":7,\"Value\":\"MM 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Comment\",\"DisplayOrder\":8,\"Value\":\"PERSONAL\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Supplier\",\"DisplayOrder\":9,\"Value\":\"GOUR\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1}],\"Unit\":\"08\"}]",
            "NextLevelZoomType": 2
        },
        {
            "RowType": 3,
            "Sl": {
                "Value": "3. ",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Particulars": {
                "Value": " M",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value1": {
                "Value": "2",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value2": {
                "Value": "4455",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value3": {
                "Value": "15",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "NextLevelZoomData": "[{\"UnitFields\":[{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Challan No.\",\"DisplayOrder\":1,\"Value\":\"2 / 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"No. of Days\",\"DisplayOrder\":2,\"Value\":\"153\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Bal. Qty\",\"DisplayOrder\":3,\"Value\":\"1.00 PCS\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":0},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Item\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"Value\":\"WAVE\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Rate\",\"DisplayOrder\":5,\"Value\":\"398.00\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Sale\",\"DisplayOrder\":6,\"Value\":\"L A\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Location\",\"DisplayOrder\":7,\"Value\":\" FLOOR\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Comment\",\"DisplayOrder\":8,\"Value\":\"SELECTION~\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Supplier\",\"DisplayOrder\":9,\"Value\":\"gtt\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1}],\"Unit\":\"09\"},{\"UnitcodeFields\":[{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Challan No.\",\"DisplayOrder\":1,\"Value\":\"1/ 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"No. of Days\",\"DisplayOrder\":2,\"Value\":\"139\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Bal. Qty\",\"DisplayOrder\":3,\"Value\":\"1.00 PCS\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":0},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Item\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"Value\":\"EMjB\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Rate\",\"DisplayOrder\":5,\"Value\":\"37,590.00\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Sale\",\"DisplayOrder\":6,\"Value\":\"L A\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Location\",\"DisplayOrder\":7,\"Value\":\"MM 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Comment\",\"DisplayOrder\":8,\"Value\":\"PERSONAL\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Supplier\",\"DisplayOrder\":9,\"Value\":\"GOUR\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1}],\"Unit\":\"08\"}]",
            "NextLevelZoomType": 2
        },
        {
            "RowType": 3,
            "Sl": {
                "Value": "4. ",
                "isBold": 1,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Particulars": {
                "Value": " DESIGNS",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value1": {
                "Value": "1",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value2": {
                "Value": "2000",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "Value3": {
                "Value": "14",
                "isBold": 0,
                "isItalics": 0,
                "Levels": 1,
                "Align": 1
            },
            "NextLevelZoomData": "[{\"UnitFields\":[{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Challan No.\",\"DisplayOrder\":1,\"Value\":\"00/ 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"No. of Days\",\"DisplayOrder\":2,\"Value\":\"146\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Bal. Qty\",\"DisplayOrder\":3,\"Value\":\"1.00 PCS\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":0},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Item\",\"DisplayOrder\":4,\"Value\":\"EMB\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Rate\",\"DisplayOrder\":5,\"Value\":\"2000\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Sale\",\"DisplayOrder\":6,\"Value\":\"L A\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Location\",\"DisplayOrder\":7,\"Value\":\"MM 1\",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Comment\",\"DisplayOrder\":8,\"Value\":\"ONE \",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1},{\"AllowSort\":1,\"Caption\":\"Supplier\",\"DisplayOrder\":9,\"Value\":\"FAIR \",\"Highlight\":0,\"Visible\":1}]}]",
            "NextLevelZoomType": 2
        }


    ],
    "Status": 1,
    "Msg": "Success"
}


```[Screenshot attached on debugging ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrCOb.png
````

Comment: Did you solved that situation?